# How to use set intersection or union on 2D array in ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, set-intersection, set-union

Say I have a 2D array like so:

```
[ [0, 1], [2, 3], [0, 4] ]
```

How can I use intersection or union of those arros above to get the result of:

```
[[0, 1, 4], [2, 3]]
```

To explain the above:

1. The reason for `[0, 1, 4]` is because 0 is connected to 1 and 4
2. The reason for `[2,3]` is because 2 is only connected to 3

How can we do this using set intersection or union? I'm pretty its possible.

## Code

My current implementation is actually creating `Node` and looking for neighbours:

```rb
def connected_neighbors(astronaut)
  graph, to_return, node_a, node_b = {}, [], nil, nil

  astronaut.each do |city_a, city_b|
    node_a, node_b = (graph[city_a] || Node.new(city_a)), (graph[city_b] || Node.new(city_b))
    node_a.connect node_b
    graph[city_a] = node_a unless graph[city_a]
  end

  graph.each do |key,_|
    node = graph[key]
    to_return << [node.key, node.neighbors.collect(&:key)].flatten
  end
  to_return
end
```

The above implementation will output the expected result as above, but not for most other cases.

## Update

For case `[1, 2], [2, 3]`

The output should be `[[0], [1,2,3]]`

This is because of the range in the array is from 0 to 3.

So because 0 doesn't exist in the array, it will be separate

Comment: Can you add more cases?

Comment: Your "update" deals with the special case of zero. If `a = [[1,2], [2,3]]` can we deal with that by simply appending `[0]` to `a` as a first step, regardless of whether any of the elements (arrays) of  `a` already contain a zero? If so, I suggest you simplify your question by not mentioning the zero case. Also, if `a = [[0,1],[1,2],[2,3]]` do you wish the return value to be `[[0,1,2,3[[`?

Comment: yh sure @CarySwoveland

Answer (score 2):

This is perhaps not the most efficient way of forming the disjoint arrays, but it does produce the desired result. The proof that it works is easily established by contradiction.

```
arr = [[0,2], [1,3], [4,6], [7,9], [6,8], [5,7], [2,4], [3,7], [10,11]]

require 'set'

sets = arr.map(&:to_set)
  #=> [#<Set: {0, 2}>, #<Set: {1, 3}>, #<Set: {4, 6}>, #<Set: {7, 9}>, #<Set: {6, 8}>,
  #    #<Set: {5, 7}>, #<Set: {2, 4}>, #<Set: {3, 7}>, #<Set: {10, 11}>]

loop do
  break if sets.size == 1
  set1, set2 = sets.combination(2).find { |set1,set2| (set1 & set2).any? }
  break if set1.nil?
  set1.replace(set1 | set2)
  sets.delete(set2)
end

sets.map(&:to_a)
  #=> [[0, 2, 4, 6, 8], [1, 3, 7, 9, 5], [10, 11]]
```

I’ve used sets instead of arrays to speed the union and intersection calculations.

The steps can be illustrated by including some `puts` statements.

```
sets = arr.map(&:to_set)

loop do
  puts "(#{sets.size} sets at beginning of loop"
  puts "  #{sets}"
  puts "  break as sets.size == 1" if sets.size == 1
  break if sets.size == 1
  set1, set2 = sets.combination(2).find { |set1,set2| (set1 & set2).any? }
  if set1.nil?
    puts "    After find, set1 = nil, so break" if set1.nil?
  else
    puts "    After find, set1 = #{set1}"
    puts "                set2 = #{set2}"
  end
  break if set1.nil?
  set1.replace(set1 | set2)
  sets.delete(set2)
  puts "  sets after set1 |= set2 and sets.delete(set2)"
  puts "  #{sets}" 
end

sets.map(&:to_a)
```

prints the following.

```
(9) sets at beginning of loop
  [#<Set: {0, 2}>, #<Set: {1, 3}>, #<Set: {4, 6}>, #<Set: {7, 9}>, #<Set: {6, 8}>,
   #<Set: {5, 7}>, #<Set: {2, 4}>, #<Set: {3, 7}>, #<Set: {10, 11}>]
    After find, set1 = #<Set: {0, 2}>
                set2 = #<Set: {2, 4}>
 sets after set1 |= set2 and sets.delete(set2)
   [#<Set: {0, 2, 4}>, #<Set: {1, 3}>, #<Set: {4, 6}>, #<Set: {7, 9}>,
    #<Set: {6, 8}>, #<Set: {5, 7}>, #<Set: {3, 7}>, #<Set: {10, 11}>]
```

```
(8) sets at beginning of loop
  [#<Set: {0, 2, 4}>, #<Set: {1, 3}>, #<Set: {4, 6}>, #<Set: {7, 9}>,
   #<Set: {6, 8}>, #<Set: {5, 7}>, #<Set: {3, 7}>, #<Set: {10, 11}>]
    After find, set1 = #<Set: {0, 2, 4}>
                set2 = #<Set: {4, 6}>
 sets after set1 |= set2 and sets.delete(set2)
   [#<Set: {0, 2, 4, 6}>, #<Set: {1, 3}>, #<Set: {7, 9}>, #<Set: {6, 8}>,
    #<Set: {5, 7}>, #<Set: {3, 7}>, #<Set: {10, 11}>]
```

```
(7) sets at beginning of loop
  [#<Set: {0, 2, 4, 6}>, #<Set: {1, 3}>, #<Set: {7, 9}>, #<Set: {6, 8}>,
   #<Set: {5, 7}>, #<Set: {3, 7}>, #<Set: {10, 11}>]
    After find, set1 = #<Set: {0, 2, 4, 6}>
                set2 = #<Set: {6, 8}>
 sets after set1 |= set2 and sets.delete(set2)
   [#<Set: {0, 2, 4, 6, 8}>, #<Set: {1, 3}>, #<Set: {7, 9}>, #<Set: {5, 7}>,
    #<Set: {3, 7}>, #<Set: {10, 11}>]
```

```
(6) sets at beginning of loop
  [#<Set: {0, 2, 4, 6, 8}>, #<Set: {1, 3}>, #<Set: {7, 9}>, #<Set: {5, 7}>,
   #<Set: {3, 7}>, #<Set: {10, 11}>]
    After find, set1 = #<Set: {1, 3}>
                set2 = #<Set: {3, 7}>
 sets after set1 |= set2 and sets.delete(set2)
   [#<Set: {0, 2, 4, 6, 8}>, #<Set: {1, 3, 7}>, #<Set: {7, 9}>, #<Set: {5, 7}>,
    #<Set: {10, 11}>]
```

```
(5) sets at beginning of loop
  [#<Set: {0, 2, 4, 6, 8}>, #<Set: {1, 3, 7}>, #<Set: {7, 9}>, #<Set: {5, 7}>,
   #<Set: {10, 11}>]
    After find, set1 = #<Set: {1, 3, 7}>
                set2 = #<Set: {7, 9}>
 sets after set1 |= set2 and sets.delete(set2)
   [#<Set: {0, 2, 4, 6, 8}>, #<Set: {1, 3, 7, 9}>, #<Set: {5, 7}>, #<Set: {10, 11}>]
```

```
(4) sets at beginning of loop
  [#<Set: {0, 2, 4, 6, 8}>, #<Set: {1, 3, 7, 9}>, #<Set: {5, 7}>, #<Set: {10, 11}>]
    After find, set1 = #<Set: {1, 3, 7, 9}>
                set2 = #<Set: {5, 7}>
 sets after set1 |= set2 and sets.delete(set2)
   [#<Set: {0, 2, 4, 6, 8}>, #<Set: {1, 3, 7, 9, 5}>, #<Set: {10, 11}>]
```

```
(3) sets at beginning of loop
  [#<Set: {0, 2, 4, 6, 8}>, #<Set: {1, 3, 7, 9, 5}>, #<Set: {10, 11}>]
    After find, set1 = nil, so break
```

```
sets.map(&:to_a)
  #=> [[0, 2, 4, 6, 8], [1, 3, 7, 9, 5], [10, 11]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking for, maybe you can group:

```
astr = [ [0, 1], [1, 3], [3, 4], [2, 5], [5, 6] ]

mapp = astr.map.with_index do |_, i|
  res = []
  astr[i..-1].each do |e|
    if res.empty?
      res = res && e 
    else
      res = res + e unless (res & e).empty?
    end
  end
  res.uniq
end.slice_when { |j, k| j.size <= k.size }.map(&:first)


mapp #=> [[0, 1, 3, 4], [2, 5, 6]]
```

In case of `astr = [ [0, 1], [1, 3], [3, 4], [2, 5], [5, 0] ]`, it returns

```
#=> [[0, 1, 3, 4, 5], [2, 5, 0]]
```

In case of `astr = [ [1, 2], [2, 3] ]`, it returns

```
#=> [[1, 2, 3]]
```

Feel free to `.unshift [0]` in case result size is 1 or less.

Comment: What about the test case for `[1, 2], [2, 3]`? The output should be `[[0], [1,2,3]]` because 0 didn't exist in the case